# How to show Android Notification within a timeframe

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I want to show a notification every 15 minutes only between 8:00 and 16:00. Here is the code:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendarStartOfTheDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendarEndOfTheDay = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendarStartOfTheDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendarStartOfTheDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendarStartOfTheDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        calendarEndOfTheDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendarEndOfTheDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendarEndOfTheDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null && calendar.getTimeInMillis() > calendarStartOfTheDay.getTimeInMillis() && calendar.getTimeInMillis() < calendarEndOfTheDay.getTimeInMillis()) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 15 * 60 * 1000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
        }
```

Is there a solution except checking the current time before `notificationManager.notify()`
If this is the only solution, wouldn't it drain your battery too much during the night?

Comment: Notification Builder has the method setWhen(). Check if you could possibly send all the notifications in advance, for a day. Then you only need to schedule one job per day.

Comment: Please check my answer hope this may help to you.

Comment: Thanks @InsaneCat, I will check the library and WorkManager. Not sure if this will fit my requirements as I am not doing any server work. I just need to show a notification each 15 minutes during the work day. The notification comes from the app and it doesn't require any specific conditions and it is not coming from the server.

Comment: @vadber check my updated new answer. it's working

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by job scheduler in android. As alarm manager is outdated and 
no longer used. Job scheduler also provide you with the flexibility of scheduling the task to run under specific conditions,
 such as:

Device is charging

Device is connected to an unmetered network

Device is idle

Start before a certain deadline

Start within a predefined time window, e.g., within the next hour

Start after a minimal delay, e.g., wait a minimum of 10 minutes

you can follow this link to implement this

https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129